# RegEx to replace entire string with first two values

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I'm trying to come up with a regex expression to replace an entire string with just the first two values. Examples:

- Entire String: AO SMITH 100108283 4500W/240V SCREW-IN ELEMENT, 11"
- First Two Values: AO SMITH
- Entire String: BRA14X18HEBU / P11-042 / 310-470NL BRASS 1/4 x 1/8 HEX
  BUSHING
- First Two Values: BRA14X18HEBU / P11-042
- Entire String: TWO-HOLE PIPE STRAP 4" 008004EG 72E 4
- First Two Values: TWO-HOLE PIPE

The caveat is I'm wanting to preserve any kind of special characters and not count them, like "/"'s and "-"'s. The current code I've written does not, instead leaves the new values entirely blank. Only the first example above works.

Here's what I've got so far:

Matching Value:

```
^(\w+) +(\w+).+$
```

New Value:

```
$1 $2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be using a single capture group and use that in the replacement.

```
^(\w+(?:-\w+)?(?: +\/)? +\w+(?:-\w+)?).+
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\w+(?:-\w+)?`Match 1+ word charss with an optional part to match a `-` and 1+ word chars
  - `(?: +\/)?` Optionally match   `/`
  - `+\w+(?:-\w+)?` Match 1+ word charss with an optional part to match a `-` and 1+ word chars
- `)` Close group 1
- `.+` Match 1+ times any char (the rest of the line)

If there can be more than 1 hyphen, you can use `*` instead of `?`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lT4mKR/1)

Output

```
AO SMITH
BRA14X18HEBU / P11-042
TWO-HOLE PIPE
```

A broader match could be matching non word chars in between the words

```
^(\w+(?:-\w+)*[\W\r\n]+\w+(?:-\w+)*).+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4cLhoz/1)

Comment: This works! Although if there are more than 1 hyphen and/or 1 slash, how exactly would the new replacement rule look?

Would it be like this:
^(\w+(*:-\w+)*(*: +\/)* +\w+(*:-\w+)*).+

Comment: @Marc I added a bit broader match https://regex101.com/r/4cLhoz/1 or indeed you can use the `*` as a quantifier https://regex101.com/r/rULAtN/1

Comment: @The_forth_bird Thanks! Let me give this one a try. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Marc If there can only be spaces or `/` you can also specify those in a character class `^(\w+(?:-\w+)*[\/ ]+\w+(?:-\w+)*).+` https://regex101.com/r/O9pljd/1

Comment: @The_forth_bird The broader match did the trick! Thank you once again!